this.$.... not working after migrating Vue2 -> Vue3
So I just started migrating using the migration guide and the Compat build so we could more smoothly transition. I have setup the vue.config.js like:
chainWebpack: (config) => {
// Set alias for Vue compatibility build
config.resolve.alias.set('vue', '@vue/compat');

// Set other aliases
config.resolve.alias
  .set('@common', path.resolve('src/common'))
  .set('@', path.resolve('src/'));

// Add extensions
config.resolve.extensions
  .merge(['.js', '.ts', '.tsx']);

// Modify vue-loader options
config.module
  .rule('vue')
  .use('vue-loader')
  .tap((options) => {
    return {
      ...options,
      compilerOptions: {
        compatConfig: {
          MODE: 2,
        },
      },
    };
  });
 },

And changed my main.ts to:
  createApp({
router,
i18n,
render: () =>
  h(App, {
    logo: '/img/sodra-logo.svg',
  }),
  }).mount('#app');

Now when running npm run serve i get tons of errors and almost all seems to be similar to
TS2339: Property '$t' does not exist on type 'HomePage'.
311 |       {
312 |         routeName: routeNameHomePage,
> 313 |         name: this.$t('breadcrumbs.' + routeNameHomePage).toString(),
        |                    ^^
    314 |       },
    315 |     ];
    316 |

But it is not only for the localization; it seems to be anything with this.$ like it gives the same type of error for this.$route, and this.$moment etc. I have tried to find if this has been changed, but I cannot find out that the use of $ would be deprecated. And since it affects all $. O guess there is some config I have missed somewhere.
My tsconfig.json is like this since there is a typescript error thrown:
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": ["vite/client", "vue", "webpack-env", "jest"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "@common/*": ["src/common/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}


You might try looking at the provide/inject of plugins https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject

Your question is too general, it needs more focus. For each of those variables you have to go to its corresponding plugin and see how they now provide their configuration in Vue3. If you have trouble with any one in particular, ask a specific question about that issue, providing a runnable [mcve]. We can't give you a general answer, because there isn't one, it could be different depending on how the plugin was migrated to vue3.

In Vue 3, the this.$ syntax, that let you use any global functions or variables, was replaced by hooks. which are a set of functions that start with use. For example:

this.$router => useRouter()
this.$route => useRoute()
this.$v => useVuelidate()

You can also create your own hooks by simply creating a js function in a file and exporting it.
const foo = new Foo();

function useFoo() {
    return foo;
}

export default useFoo;

this will let you access foo globally, the same way this.$foo theoretically would too, if it existed.

In Vue 3, the this.$ syntax, which lets you use any package or function globally by default, is deprecated in favor of importing the function manually on a per-component basis.
For example, you would have to do this instead:
<script>
import { t } from '@/i18n'

export default defineComponent({
 const returnTranslatedName = computed(() => t('breadcrumbs.path.name')
})
</script>

<template>
 <div>
  {{t('breadcrumbs.path.name'}}
   <!-- OR -->
  {{returnTRanslatedName}}
 </div>
</template>

Let me know if this helps or if you have further questions
